# JavaMail's IdleManager - appropriate thread pool size

Tags: jakarta-mail

When using JavaMail's IdleManager to monitor IMAP folders for new messages what is the appropriate thread pool size?

Do I need one thread per watched folder, or will a smaller thread pool work?

If I wanted to watch 1,000 folders say, what would be an appropriate thread pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you're going to need to tune this based on your environment.  You need one thread for each Folder that you expect to simultaneously have new messages available, so it will depend on how "active" your Folders are.  It will also depend on how much processing you're doing for each message, since a thread will be tied up while the message is being processed.

Comment: Thanks Bill - so the upshot is that IdleManager is essentially non-blocking?

Comment: Not completely.  Be sure to set timeouts for the Folders as well.  When a read timeout is set, each watched Folder that has data ready will be processed by the Executor, which may create a new thread for each Folder.  Processing the data for each Folder will generate events that will be sent to your listeners using the event processing strategy you've configured - see the `mail.event.*` properties.